# NX is not able to purge tailwind third-party library's classNames

Tags: tailwind-css, monorepo, nrwl-nx, nx-monorepo

I'm working on an NX project where I've organized different repositories for components, alongside incorporating a third-party Tailwind component library. Currently, I'm facing issues with duplicate classNames being generated in the CSS bundle. Despite following the instructions outlined here, the problem persists. Can someone advise on how to configure the third-party Tailwind component library in NX to prevent the generation of duplicate classNames?